# What is the rationale behind allowing multiple ampersands when referencing a value?

Tags: rust

I can write this code to reference the pointer of variable `i`:

```
let i = 10;
let j = &i;
```

But why does the Rust compiler allow multiple ampersands when referencing a variable?

Example:

```
let i = 10;
let j = &&&&&&i; // this is still valid and points to reference of i
```

Comment: Why shouldn't it? Reference to a reference (like pointer to a pointer) is a valid concept.

Comment: There are many applications of references to references. They appear naturally in generic code. Mutable references to a reference allow updating the inner reference and make it point elsewhere.

Comment: there is no reason to make an exception when this doesn't make any problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Rust, references are values too so you can make a reference to a reference.

```
let v: i32 = 5;
let r0 = &v; // Reference that points to `v`
let r1_1 = &r0; // Reference that points to r0. Equivalent of `&&v`.
let r1_2 = &r0; // Reference that points to r0. Equivalent of `&&v`.
let mut r2 = &r1_1; // Reference that points to r1_1. Equivalent of `&&&v`.
// Because it is a value, we can change it! Now it points to r1_2.
// Equivalent of `&&&v`.
r2 = &r1_2; 

let another_val = 9;
r2 = &&&another_val;
```

Making reference like `&&&v` is possible because Rust extends lifetime of temporaries if you take reference to them. You can read about them in [specification](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/destructors.html#temporary-lifetime-extension).

You can think about it like this:

```rust
// Original code
let v: i32 = 5;
let r = &&&v;

// Compiler generates something like this:
let v: i32 = 5;
let __r0: &i32 = &v;
let __r1: &&i32 = &__r0;
let r: &&&i32 = &__r1;
```